# Unable to change domain password from Windows 11 with samba4 domain controller

Tags: windows, ubuntu, domain-controller, samba4

I've set up a samba dc on Ubuntu and connected successfully a blanc win 11 vm. Everything works fin so far, but when I try to change the password in that win11 vm using ctrl+alt+del, it does not work, instead, I get an error message like "the configuration information from domain controller could not be loaded..."

The DC password settings are like this

```
Password complexity: off
Store plaintext passwords: off
Password history length: 0
Minimum password length: 6
Minimum password age (days): 0
Maximum password age (days): 0
Account lockout duration (mins): 30
Account lockout threshold (attempts): 0
Reset account lockout after (mins): 30
```

I also checked if I am able to login to that very win11 vm using a different user and this works, too, so I guess there is no connection issue here.

Sorry for the question, maybe it's obvious but I haven't found the solution.